# SQL left join for users table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, self-join

I have the following example table (simplified from what I really have as there are a few more joins in there)

```
|permission|username|
| perm1    | u1     |
| perm2    | u1     |
| perm3    | u1     |
| perm1    | u2     |
| perm4    | u2     |
```

I have many users and many groups in this table

I am having trouble with user permissions where some users can do things in my application and others cannot. At the moment I am having to manually go through and figure out what the differences are.

I want to crate a query from the above table that gives me an answer like this

```
|permission| u1 | u2 |
|perm1     | 1  | 1  |
|perm2     | 1  | 0  |
|perm3     | 1  | 0  |
|perm4     | 0  | 1  |
```

I do not really want 1 and 0 under the users but I want something to I can easily visualise that user 1 has these permissions and user2 does not. This would be really useful for me to ensure that users have the same permissions.

I have done the SQL to get the top table so I can see the permissions.

I was thinking that some sort of left join on itself might the answer there but everything I try seems to end up as invalid SQL.

Any hints please? Im happy to experiment if I get a starting point :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "pivoting".  One way to do that is a `group by`, like:

```
select  permission
,       count(case when username = 'u1' then 1 end) as User1
,       count(case when username = 'u2' then 1 end) as User2
,       count(case when username = 'u3' then 1 end) as User3
,       ...
from    YourTable
group by
        permission
```

It looks like Oracle supports [the `PIVOT` keyword](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php).  You can use it to accomplish the same thing:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
pivot   (
        count(*) as HasPermission
        for (username) in ('u1', 'u2', 'u3', ...)
        );
```

[Example for both approaches at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca18c/9/1)